# Why i always need to chain FileReader to other readers?

Tags: java, io

Why i always need to chain FileReader to other readers like BufferedReader or Scanner ?
Why i can't use just a FileScanner since it is Convenience for reading character files.
I'm just practicing and i do not care about the performance or functionality. Yet there is one method  public int read() for FileReader and it return int, how can i use that integer number for chars?

Comment: You can, there's nothing stopping you. Often though, it's simpler easier to read a file line by line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BufferedReader` is mainly used because it is more efficient than a `FileReader`. The difference between the two is that a `FileReader` is used to read characters from a file whereas `BufferedReader` wraps around `FileReader` and uses it to buffer the input (hence the name `BufferedReader`). This leads to passing `FileReader` to `BufferedReader` ending up with a more efficient way of reading.

But as you asked in the question... It is perfectly fine using `FileReader` as long as you are okay dealing with what it provides as functionality.

Comment: Hey, I'm just practicing and i do not care about the performance or functionality. There is one method for FileReader for reading and its
public int read();  Since it returns int how can i use it for chars ?

Comment: @KağanUğur The method `read()` returns a single character from the file but it returns it as an `int`. You can cast it to `char` like so: `char c = (char) fileReader.read()`